# Google map image icon can not load in browser

Tags: html, css

Please see my code and clarify me for solution.

```
<div style="height: 30px; background-image: url(http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png;);background-repeat: no-repeat">
    <div style="padding-left: 30px">
        Blue
    </div>
</div>
```

When I took url 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png' and paste in browser then it shows an image. But in my code it shows as Failed to load given url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `blue.png;);` to `blue.png);`

```
<div style="height: 30px; background-image: url(http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png);
                                background-repeat: no-repeat">
                                <div style="padding-left: 30px">
                                    Blue</div>
                            </div>
```